# encounter error when adding a new tab in the back office, prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I don't know if there are many people working with Prestashop here....anyway, i am facing a problem and i cant find an answer.

I am trying to add a new tab to the back end, but all the get is this message:

**An error occurred while creating object.Tab()**

I also tried to add a new tab on a fresh installed prestashop, also encountered this problem. the version that i am using is 1.4.5.1.

I also tried to find a solution and i found a ticket describing this problem, but still no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys this is actually a 1.4.5.1 version's bug, i upgrade to 1.4.6.2 everything just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is helpful, but check this if it helps you in some sense, its something about database tables:

```
http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFI-4171?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs
```

Comment: Hmm.. i actually found this ticket before, but i am not familiar with database..I guess i will try out the latest version of prestashop 1st. Thanks man:)